# django - 'int' object has no attribute 'keys'

Tags: django

```
t_cat_id = t_cat.id
cursor.execute("select offered_item,offered_item_category_id from foundation_swaptable where accepted_item = %s", t_cat.id)
```

the code above throws the exception below:

'int' object has no attribute 'keys'

when I surround t_cat.id with square brackets as below:

```
cursor.execute("select offered_item,offered_item_category_id from foundation_swaptable where accepted_item = %s", [t_cat.id])
```

the error is gone.

where t_cat is an mptt category object which I fetch as below:

```
MpttCategory.objects.get(category_name=t_category)
```

and it has an id column in DB representation which is integer.

can anyone tell me why I get this exception. I just can't associate a meaning with the error.
please tell me if more info is needed..

ps. I am a little drunk :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like [the documentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) says, the second argument must be a sequence or mapping.